# How to go to the end of the line even in on a wrapped line?

Tags: cursor-movement, wrapping

I would like to map `<End>` and `<Home>` to go to the end or beginning of the current line (not the screen), even if the cursor is on a wrapped line:

```
|1 First line.      |
|2 This is some very| <- Wrapped line 
|  long text        |
|3                  |
```

So here what should be the mappings:

```
<Home>  Cursor go to the first letter of visible line (wrapped or not).
<End>   Cursor go beyond the last letter of visible line (wrapped or not).
```

An important thing is that I use `virtualedit`:

```
set virtualedit=all
noremap <Up> gk
noremap <Down> gj
noremap k gk
noremap j gj
```

For a normal line, this can be solved using these mappings:

```
noremap <End> $l
noremap <Home> 0
"i_<End> already mapped
"i_<Home> already mapped
```

However on a wrapped line none of the above mappings work.

Here below the cases that must work:

```
|1 First line.       | Initial                   
       ^
|1 First line.       | <Home>                    (1)
   ^      
|1 First line.       | <End>                     (2)
              ^
|1 First line.       | <Home>                    
   ^                   l<Down>
|2 This is some very |                           
    ^
|2 This is some very | <End>                    (3)
                    ^
|2 This is some very | <Home>                    (4)
   ^                   l<Down>
|  long text         |                           
    ^ 
|  long text         | <Home>                    (5)
   ^
|  long text         | <End>                     (6)
            ^
```

The solution proposed by [statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) in his answer works for `<Home>`, but not really for `<End>`. So, I added a `l` to the `<End>` mapping. Then all the cases pass, but (3) that goes on the next line.

```
nnoremap <silent> <End>  :set virtualedit=<CR>g$:set virtualedit=all<CR>l 
nnoremap <silent> <Home> :set virtualedit=<CR>g0:set virtualedit=all<CR>
```

Most editors solve case (3) by adding a virtual blank column at the end of the screen, so the cursor can be virtually placed here in this particular case.

How can I achieve the same behavior in Vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `g0` and `g$` which are the equivalent of `0` and `$` for wrapped lines. See [`:h g0`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#g0), [`:h g$`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#g$) and even [`:h g^`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#g%5E).

To quote the doc about `g$`:

> When lines wrap ('wrap' on): To the last character of
>   the screen line and [count - 1] screen lines downward
>   |inclusive|.  Differs from "$" when a line is wider
>   than the screen.
>
> When lines don't wrap ('wrap' off): To the rightmost
>   character of the current line that is visible on the
>   screen.  Differs from "$" when the last character of
>   the line is not on the screen or when a count is used.
>   Additionally, vertical movements keep the column,
>   instead of going to the end of the line.

---

**EDIT**

About the `virtualedit` option maybe you could try something like:

```
nnoremap <silent> <end> :set virtualedit=<CR>g$:set virtualedit=all<CR>
```

The mapping can be explained like this:

```
nnoremap                   Create a normal mode mapping
<silent>                   Make the mapping silent to avoid messages in the command line
<end>                      The key to map
:set virtualedit=<CR>      Unset virtualedit
g$                         Use g$ normally
:set virtualedit=all<CR>   Set the virtualedit option again
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, on my system `g$` moves the cursor on the `.` of your first line example. Have you tried using it with `vim -u NONE`? Where does `g$` move your cursor?

Comment: Then it is an option in your vimrc which is causing this. You should read the doc I linked and probably play with the `wrap` related options. You can also have a look at [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to help you debug your vimrc.

Comment: @nowox actually the doc for `g$` says `When 'virtualedit' is enabled moves to the end of the screen line.` so this is probably the option to tweak in your vimrc :)

Comment: @nowox see my edit.

Comment: I've edited my question (again), and I removed my comments.